# java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I was running an application on ibm liberty profile. It has a security certificate too. When I try to run this application it gives me the login screen but when I try to login, it thorows the follwing error. Could someone please help me to fix the error?

```
[ERROR] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.getWriter:813'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRVE0199E: OutputStream already obtained
```

Comment: Give...us...code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your application is calling both getWriter() and getOutputStream() on the servlet response object (HttpServletResponse).  Per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream--), you must call one or the other -- and an IllegalStateException would be thrown if you call one after previously calling the other.

The solution to be to use only one of these methods (I think getWriter() is preferred).  If you are using third party libraries (like Spring) that might be calling these methods on the servlet response object, then your best course of action is probably to change your code to call the same method that they are.

Hope this helps, Andy

Comment: Just a small change in the answer. getWriter() is preferred is preferred when dealing with textual data. For binary data getOutputStream() is correct.